# Group tuples by field1 OR field2 in PIG?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

given tuples with two fields:
(x,y)

Group them together based on either having a common value for field x or field y.

For example, given:

```
(1,a)
(2,a)
(2,b)
(3,c)
(3,d)
```

If done correctly, this would result in the list being split into two groups.

group1:

```
(1,a)
(2,a)
(2,b)
```

group2:

```
(3,c)
(3,d)
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
a = LOAD 'givenTuples' using PigStorage(",");
b = GROUP a by $0;
matchleft = foreach b {
   --join $1 of b tuples with $0 of a; 
}
```

but a join can't be used in a nested foreach. i'm guessing this problem can't be solved in Map-reduce without an unknown amount of map-reduces.

Comment: It's not clear what logic you are trying to apply. Can you be more concrete?  How did you choose which records went to group1 and which to group2?

Comment: tuples are placed into a group if they have a common value in each field. (1,a) and (2,a) both have 'a' in the second field, so are grouped. (2,b) shares '2' with (2,a) in the first field, so it is grouped with both (1,a) and (2,a). (3,c) amd (3,d) share '3' in the first field, so they are grouped. (3,c) and (3,d) do not share any common fields with either (1,a),(2,a) or (2,b), so they are not grouped with group (1,a),(2,a),(2,c). this results in two groups: [(1,a),(2,a),(2,b)], [(3,c),(3,d)].

Comment: Or, think of each tuple as a bag. Two bags can be combined if any tuple of the first bag shares a field value with a tuple of a second bag.

Comment: It doesn't have an answer posted, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149663/group-by-x-or-y-in-pig

Comment: For these types of problems the best way to usually solve it is by writing a UDF, either in Java, Python, etc. For example you could write an EvalFunc that takes a single DataBag and produces a bag of bags.